# When searching in Android Studio, is it possible to expand all search nodes?

Tags: find, android-studio

When searching in Android Studio, is it possible to expand all search node results without having to click the triangle to expand each one individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the Expand All button or hold CTRL and the NUMPAD + key.

[image]

To unexpand, hold CTRL and the NUMPAD - key.